# Should I delete unused html?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

When using Asp.net server controls, especially formviews, I often don't use all possible modes. So I end up with a ton of template HTML that is never going to be used.  This is a pain to work with when I'm in HTML Source mode.  Is there any reason why I shouldn't just delete the excess HTML?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. If you know that you're never going to need it, just delete it. ;)

Answer (score 3):

If you dont need it, delete it. If you need it in the future you can always get it from source control.

Answer (score 0):

Removing unused html from your file will make it smaller, decreasing the file size that needs to get transmitted over the wire.